# Por que las validaciones con regex se traban en caso de que solo se valide una parte y la otra no?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

```py
import asyncio
import re
   
def know_about_that_game(input_text, text):
    time = 0
    input_text_to_check = input_text.lower()
    
    regex_patron_00 = r"\s*\¿?(?:para jugar a los |para jugar a las |para que podamos jugar al |para que podamos jugar a |para que puedas jugar al |para que puedas jugar|para que puedas jugar|para jugar a |para jugar al |para jugar |los |las |lo |la )\s*((?:\w+\s*)+) \s*\¿?(?:se necesita del |se necesitaria del |se necesita de los |se necesita de las |se necesita de la |se necesita de el |se necesita de |se necesitaria de los |se necesitaria de las |se necesitaria de la |se necesitaria de el |se necesitaria de |se necesitaria |se necesitarian de |se necesitarian |se necesitan |se necesita |sirven para lo |sirven para la|sirven para los |sirven para las )\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"

    m = re.search(regex_patron_00, input_text_to_check, re.IGNORECASE) #Con esto valido la regex haber si entra o no en el bloque de code

    if m:
        print("A")
        word, association = m.groups()
        word = word.strip()
        association = association.strip()
        text = "Se valido,  word : " + str(word) + " ,  association : " + str(association)
        return text

    text = "No se valido!"
    return text


input_text = str(input())
text = ""

print(know_about_that_game(input_text, text))
```

El programa se traba cuando una de las condiciones de la validación de la regex se cumple y la otra no, y solo queda presionar varias veces Ctrl + C para cerrarle.

Por ejemplo:

`para juddddgar a los dados rojos es necesasssssria la suerte` ---> no lo valida pero no se traba

`para jugar a los dados rojos es necesasssssria la suerte` ---> se traba el programa

`para jugar a los dados rojos es necesaria la suerte` ---> se valida y no se traba

Como podría arreglar este code? yo habia pensado en usar threads de modo que habra 2 threads, uno con la validacion regex y el otro con un timer, y que si el timer llega a tal valor entonces que cierre todos los threads abiertos, y continue con el programa principal antes de la bifurcacion, aunque no se si es una buena solución.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Haber, tienes una expresión regular muuuuyyyy larga y de por sí estás ya son lenta, con la tuya debes estar ralentizando demasiado tu programa

Comment: Yo pense lo mismo, pero hoy por la tarde me fui a hacer unas compras, y la expresion seguia maso menos por 2 horas y media (no creo que sea un problema de demora). Realmente no crei que avance mas y le cerre. Por eso pense en los threads para poder ponerle un limite maximo al tiempo de ejecucion de una tarea. Ademas lo curioso es que solo se traba si tan solo uno (y no los 2) `(?: )` fallase.

Comment: La demora esta definitivamente en el `search()` supongo que este es internamente un bucle de comparaciones, pero por algun motivo quedara en infinito o algo asi, cuando una de las 2 validaciones fallase.

Comment: Yo no me pondría a isar threads en un escenario como este, el error es curioso y trataría de encontrar el origen del problema

Comment: Se podrian plantear 2 regex separadas? Osea hacer todo lo primero y extraer la primera palabra, luego agarrar la otra mitad y recortar la segunda palabra en caso de que tambien se de la segunda regex, y en el caso de que se cumplan ambos if ahi devolver el text con un return, eso es lo unico que se me ocurre aunque tendria complicaciones para recortarlo y para extraer las palabras. Es lo unico que se me ocurre, lo probe en 2 computadoras y ese error se repite, realmente no se me ocurre como solucionarle.

Comment: Y respecto a lo del tiempo, insisto que no creo que luego de dejar mas de 2 horas con el equipo prendido y todos los programas cerrados, ese `search()` avance, incluso para un laptop de recursos medio bajos, considero que es bastante tiempo, osea que asumo que es un error de code.

Comment: ok.. varias cosas.. para lo de los threads, lee aca: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3360/qué-es-el-problema-xy ...

Comment: Lo otro, para poder depuras una regex, deberias poder explicar que es lo que trata de resolver, cuales son las cadenas validas y cuales las invalidas. Una regex es un proceso muy pero muy caro en tiempos computacionales... yo no se que estas tratando de validar, pero validar una cadena completa, con una regex, parece algo que no suena nada logico..... Una regex, arma un arbol de posibilidades en memoria, y despues, por cada caracter, recorre todo el arbol a ver si llega hasta un nodo terminal... es algo pesado y costoso....

Comment: @gbianchi tienes razon, igual la preg la oriente al problema, solo al final aclare lo que intente, mas queda en enfasis a que no es un tema de que la regex necesite mas tiempo

Comment: yo creo que mas que una regexp.. necesitas un analizador lexico... esto no suena logico asi....

Comment: Uso regex porque con el analizador lexico lo podria recortar estructuras, aqui estoy extrayendo 2 palabras de ahi

Comment: que palabras estas extrayendo? bajo que concepto? tal vez, solo deberias buscar eso?

Comment: Por ejemplo, "para jugar a los bolos son realmente necesarios los zapatos" es el input y el output es word = "bolos" y association = "zapatos", asi funciona el programa pero hasta ahi va bien, el problema es cuando le metes un error en "para jugar a los" o en "son realmente necesarios los" , si metes error en uno si y en otro no, el programa se congela en `search()`, por eso yo asumia lo de un posible bucle infinito que se haga dentro de la funcion intentando validar algo

Comment: agarre tu expresion.. la meti en regex101 y le puse la cadena que te da error.. y efectivamente, tu regex esta mal y da error: "Catastrophic backtracking has been detected and the execution of your expression has been halted. To find out more and what this is, please read the following article: " https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: y tu regex, donde le dice que las palabras a buscar son bolos y zapatos?? como hace eso???

Comment: mira ahi mando una captura en la update de la pregunta, y te muestro como anda

Comment: @gbianchi ahi la he actualizado, ese que vez es el caso donde no metes errores en las opciones, osea donde las 2 opciones son correctas

Answer (score 0):

Tienes una expresión regular muy larga, tu computadora no puede con algunas validaciones ya que debe recorer casi toda la expresión.

Mi consejo es: divide cada expresión dentro de una lista:

```
EXPRESIONES = {
  "uno": "para jugar a los",
  "dos": "para jugar a las",
  "tres": "para que podamos jugar al",
  # ...
}
```

entonces recole la lista para encontrar cohincidencias, para esto ayudate de la funcion **find()** de las cadenas.

```
def validar_expresion(texto):
  for expresion in EXPRESIONES: 
    print(EXPRESIONES[expresion])
    if texto.find(EXPRESIONES[expresion]) >= 0:
      return True
    
  return False
```

Y prueba:

```
esValido = validar_expresion("asdsa para jugar a los pepe")
```

Espero ser de ayuda.

Comment: Entiendo, aunque se me hace curioso que si llevo la regex a algo mas simple `regex_patron_00 = r"\s*\¿?(?:para jugar a los)\s*((?:\w+\s*)+) \s*\¿?(?:son realmente necesarios los)\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"` y pongo un error en el segundo `(?:)` tambien se trabara, pero si haces error en el primer  `(?:)` y en el segundo  `(?:)` entonces aun no se traba. Esta falla por lo que veo es independiente al largo de la regex, por eso pense en un problema en su doble validacion